# Legendre's three-square theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Problem:

If $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ can be represented as $ n = n_1^2 + n_2^2 + n_3^2 ,\quad n_1, n_2, n_3 \in \mathbb{Z}, $ show that then $ n \neq 4^a(8m+7)$ for $a,m \in \mathbb{Z}.$

My solution:

Since this is the beginning of a math course in Discrete Mathematics, I don't think we're supposed to use the quadratic reciprocity law, Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions nor the equivalence class of the trivial ternary quadratic form. as listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem).

It also states on Wikipedia (Why?) that every square is congruent to either $0,1,4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_8$. So the sum of three squares $n \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5, 6\} \subset \mathbb{Z}_8.$ My initial plan was to show that $ 4^a(8m+7) \in \{6,7\}$. This not true though, as $ 4^a \equiv 4 $ or $ \equiv 0 $ for $ a \geq 1 $. Thus $ 4^a(8m+7) \equiv 0 $ or $4$.

Any hints?

Muchos gracias!

Comment: On the question about $\mathbb{Z}^8$: $$0^2 = 0$$ $$1^2 = 1$$ $$2^2 = 4$$ $$3^2 = 9 = 1$$ $$4^2 = 16 = 0$$ $$5^2 = 25 = 1$$ $$6^2 = 36 = 4$$ $$7^2 = 49 = 1$$ And there are no more elements!

Comment: First, $4+1+1=6$, so you can reach the residue class $6\pmod 8$. More importantly, yes, this is a result where (as it turns out) one has to deal with the powers of $4$ separately first, before finishing it off with the $7\pmod 8$ observation. Try showing that if a multiple of $4$ can be written as the sum of three squares, then each of those squares must be even, and thus you can divide everything by $4$ and consider the new smaller number.

Comment: Sum of three squares is a multiple of 4 in $ \mathbb{Z}_8 $ or $ \mathbb{Z} $?

Comment: So $ 4^a \equiv 0, 4$ mod 8. Thus $ 4^a(8m+7) \equiv 0,4 $, but $ (8m+7) \equiv 7, \forall m$. So $ n \equiv 0,4 $, so we have the possibiltes $ \{n_1,n_2,n_3 \} \equiv (0,0,0), (0,0,4), (0,4,4) $. Is this what you meant and how do you come forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as the equation $$n=n^2_1+n^2_2+n^2_3$$ has no integral solutions if $n$ is of the form $n=8m+7$ for some integer $m$--established in the comments, we can prove that the equation
$$n=n^2_1+n^2_2+n^2_3$$ has no integral solutions if $n$ is of the form $n=4^a(8m+7)$ for some integers $m, a \ge 1$, by induction on $a$.

[**To elaborate**, as shown, there are no solutions to  $$n=n^2_1+n^2_2+n^2_3$$ for $n$ of the form $n=8m+7$ i.e., $a=0$. So fix an $a >0$. We show that if there is a solution to $$n=n^2_1+n^2_2+n^2_3$$ for any $n$ of the form $n=4^a(8m+7)$, then there must be a solution to $$\tilde{n}=\tilde{n}^2_1+\tilde{n}^2_2+\tilde{n}^2_3$$ for some $\tilde{n}$ of the form $\tilde{n}=4^{a-1}(8m+7)$. As it has already been established in the comments that there is no solution to $$\tilde{n}=\tilde{n}^2_1+\tilde{n}^2_2+\tilde{n}^2_3$$ for some $\tilde{n}$ of the form $\tilde{n}=(8m+7) =4^0(8m+7)$ this establishes the desired result.]

**The crux of the proof is** this: Suppose $n = 4^a(8m+7)$ for $a \ge 1$. Then $n \mod 4 = 0$ and as every even square is $0 \mod 4$ and every odd square is $1 \mod 4$ [check this for yourself] it follows that $n_1,n_2,n_3$ must all be even. So then this implies
$$\frac{n}{4} = \left(\frac{n_1}{2}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{n_2}{2}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{n_3}{2}\right)^2$$ must hold, with the $\left(\frac{n_i}{2}\right)$s; $i=1,2,3$ all integers and with $\frac{n}{4} = 4^{a-1}(8m+7)$.

Comment: How do you move on with the $ \frac{n}{4} = 4^{a-1}(8m +7)$?

Comment: Should you apply mod 8 on the equation $ \frac{n}{4} = 4^{a-1}(8m + 7)$?